# image url Concatenate string

Tags: asp.net

i want to achievet the following Url

```
ImageUrl='~/products_pictures/(imageId)_middle.jpg
```

im using gridview and datalist

im trying the follwoing combination but it not working

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image1"  ImageUrl='~/products_pictures/<%#Eval("Id")%>_middle.jpg' runat="server" /></td>


 <asp:Image ID="Image1"  ImageUrl=<%"~/products_pictures/"%><%#Eval("Id")%><%"_middle.jpg"%> runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `String.Format` for this. It makes concatenation much easier:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/products_pictures/{0}_middle.jpg", Eval("ID"))%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/products_pictures/<%#Eval("id") %>_middle.jpg"/>
```

If not you can put a `asp:Literal`, and a `HiddenField` to store id and in `GridView.RowDataBound` Event you can add image as a text to the literal

Comment: it not working when i try to rebuild my project it giving me error Error The server tag is not well formed

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
</td><asp:Image ID="Image1"  ImageUrl="~/products_pictures/<%#Eval("Id")%>_middle.jpg" runat="server" /></td>
```

if not debug from this:

```
</td><%#Eval("Id")%></td>
```

ells you can try

```
 <%# ((objectName)Container.DataItem).Id%>
((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The server tag is not well formed because of the quotes

put single quotes on the outside and try again

```
ImageUrl='~/products_pictures/<%#Eval("Id")%>_middle.jpg'
```

Comment: the problem im having when i check the code behind web page it adding extra bit src="products_pictures/%3C%25#Eval(%22Id%22)%25%3E_middle.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

This worked at my end:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#'~/products_pictures/' + Eval("id")+'_middle.jpg' %>"/>
```